# Spring WebFlux: Only one connection receive subscriber allowed

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, project-reactor, spring-webflux, reactor-netty

I am writing a simple app with Spring 5 Webflux and Kotlin. I am trying to implement PUT endpoint in a following way:

```
PUT("/confs/{id}", {
    val id = it.pathVariable("id")
    ServerResponse.ok().body(service.save(it.bodyToMono(Item::class.java)), Item::class.java)
})
```

The trick on save is that I try to read a city name from item, resolve geo coordinates, overwrite them in original item and then save to Mongo using Spring Data Mongo Reactive repo.

```
fun save(item: Mono<Item>): Mono<Item> {
    val geo = item.flatMap {
            val city = it.location?.city ?: "Somewhere"
            geoService.resolveGeoFromCity(city)
    }

    val zipped = item.zipWith(geo)
        .map {
            it.t1.location?.geo = it.t2
            it.t1
        }

    return repo.saveAll(zipped)
        .toMono()
}
```

Code to resolve geo coordinates is here:

```
@Service
class GeoService() {

    val client = WebClient.create("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/")

    fun resolveGeoFromCity(city: String): Mono<Geo> {
        return client.get()
                .uri("json?address=$city&key=$API_KEY&language=en")
                .exchange()
                .flatMap { it.bodyToMono(String::class.java) }
                .map { parse(it) }
    }

    private fun parse(response: String): Geo {
        val locationMap = JsonPath.read<Map<String, Double>>(response, "$.results[0].geometry.location")
        return Geo(locationMap["lat"] ?: 0.0, locationMap["lng"] ?: 0.0)
    }

}
```

The problem is that if make a PUT request I got following stacktrace. I have tried to stub Mono with `val geo = Mono.just(Geo(0.0, 0.0))` (without using WebClient) and then it works fine.

How to fix it without sacrifying functionality?)

```
    2018-01-01 01:41:00.595 ERROR 15120 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] .a.w.r.e.DefaultErrorWebExceptionHandler : Failed to handle request [PUT http://localhost:8097/confs/5a49675c910d123b1057207a]

    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only one connection receive subscriber allowed.
        at reactor.ipc.netty.channel.FluxReceive.startReceiver(FluxReceive.java:276) ~[reactor-netty-0.7.2.RELEASE.jar:0.7.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.ipc.netty.channel.FluxReceive.subscribe(FluxReceive.java:124) ~[reactor-netty-0.7.2.RELEASE.jar:0.7.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap.subscribe(FluxMap.java:62) ~[reactor-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly.subscribe(FluxOnAssembly.java:252) ~[reactor-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.ipc.netty.ByteBufFlux.subscribe(ByteBufFlux.java:242) ~[reactor-netty-0.7.2.RELEASE.jar:0.7.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek.subscribe(FluxPeek.java:83) ~[reactor-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly.subscribe(FluxOnAssembly.java:252) ~[reactor-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.ipc.netty.ByteBufFlux.subscribe(ByteBufFlux.java:242) ~[reactor-netty-0.7.2.RELEASE.jar:0.7.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap.subscribe(FluxMap.java:62) ~[reactor-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly.subscribe(FluxOnAssembly.java:252) ~[reactor-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap.subscribe(FluxFlatMap.java:97) ~[reactor-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly.subscribe(FluxOnAssembly.java:252) ~[reactor-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDoFinallyFuseable.subscribe(FluxDoFinallyFuseable.java:48) ~[reactor-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly.subscribe(FluxOnAssembly.java:252) ~[reactor-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable.subscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:63) ~[reactor-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly.subscribe(FluxOnAssembly.java:252) ~
[reactor-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal.subscribe(MonoPeekTerminal.java:61) ~[reactor-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnAssembly.subscribe(MonoOnAssembly.java:76) ~[reactor-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekFuseable.subscribe(MonoPeekFuseable.java:74) ~[reactor-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnAssembly.subscribe(MonoOnAssembly.java:76) ~[reactor-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnAssembly.subscribe(MonoOnAssembly.java:76) ~[reactor-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnAssembly.subscribe(MonoOnAssembly.java:76) ~[reactor-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnAssembly.subscribe(MonoOnAssembly.java:76) ~[reactor-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnErrorResume.subscribe(MonoOnErrorResume.java:44) ~[reactor-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnAssembly.subscribe(MonoOnAssembly.java:76) ~[reactor-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnErrorResume.subscribe(MonoOnErrorResume.java:44) ~[reactor-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnAssembly.subscribe(MonoOnAssembly.java:76) ~[reactor-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnErrorResume.subscribe(MonoOnErrorResume.java:44) ~[reactor-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnAssembly.subscribe(MonoOnAssembly.java:76) ~[reactor-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3008) ~[reactor-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.drain(MonoIgnoreThen.java:167) ~[reactor-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:56) ~[reactor-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnAssembly.subscribe(MonoOnAssembly.java:76) ~[reactor-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnErrorResume.subscribe(MonoOnErrorResume.java:44) ~[reactor-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnAssembly.subscribe(MonoOnAssembly.java:71) ~[reactor-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal.subscribe(MonoPeekTerminal.java:61) ~[reactor-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnAssembly.subscribe(MonoOnAssembly.java:76) ~[reactor-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.ipc.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.applyHandler(ChannelOperations.java:383) ~[reactor-netty-0.7.2.RELEASE.jar:0.7.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.ipc.netty.http.server.HttpServerOperations.onHandlerStart(HttpServerOperations.java:359) ~[reactor-netty-0.7.2.RELEASE.jar:0.7.2.RELEASE]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute$$$capture(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163) ~[netty-common-4.1.17.Final.jar:4.1.17.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java) ~[netty-common-4.1.17.Final.jar:4.1.17.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:403) ~[netty-common-4.1.17.Final.jar:4.1.17.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:463) ~[netty-transport-4.1.17.Final.jar:4.1.17.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858) ~[netty-common-4.1.17.Final.jar:4.1.17.Final]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
        Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
    Assembly trace from producer [reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap] :
        reactor.core.publisher.Flux.map(Flux.java:4855)
        reactor.ipc.netty.ByteBufFlux.fromInbound(ByteBufFlux.java:68)
        reactor.ipc.netty.NettyInbound.receive(NettyInbound.java:90)
        org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ReactorServerHttpRequest.getBody(ReactorServerHttpRequest.java:148)
        org.springframework.http.codec.DecoderHttpMessageReader.readMono(DecoderHttpMessageReader.java:93)
        org.springframework.http.codec.DecoderHttpMessageReader.readMono(DecoderHttpMessageReader.java:123)
        org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyExtractors.lambda$null$0(BodyExtractors.java:101)
        java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215)
        org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyExtractors.readWithMessageReaders(BodyExtractors.java:256)
        org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyExtractors.lambda$toMono$2(BodyExtractors.java:96)
        org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.DefaultServerRequest.body(DefaultServerRequest.java:126)
        org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.DefaultServerRequest.body(DefaultServerRequest.java:120)
        org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.DefaultServerRequest.bodyToMono(DefaultServerRequest.java:145)
        com.example.confs.web.ConferenceRouter$routes$1$2.invoke(ConferenceRouter.kt:31)
        com.example.confs.web.ConferenceRouter$routes$1$2.invoke(ConferenceRouter.kt:16)
        org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.RouterFunctionDsl$PUT$1.handle(RouterFunctionDsl.kt:200)
        org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.support.HandlerFunctionAdapter.handle(HandlerFunctionAdapter.java:61)
        org.springframework.web.reactive.DispatcherHandler.invokeHandler(DispatcherHandler.java:168)
        org.springframework.web.reactive.DispatcherHandler.lambda$handle$1(DispatcherHandler.java:160)
        reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:118)
        reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:67)
        reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:76)
        reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.innerNext(FluxConcatMap.java:271)
        reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapInner.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:803)
        reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:115)
        reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:67)
        reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:67)
        reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:67)
        reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:67)
        reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:1649)
        reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:1463)
        reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onSubscribe(Operators.java:1337)
        reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:54)
        reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
        reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3008)
        reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:75)
        reactor.core.publisher.Operators.complete(Operators.java:125)
        reactor.core.publisher.MonoEmpty.subscribe(MonoEmpty.java:45)
        reactor.core.publisher.MonoSwitchIfEmpty.subscribe(MonoSwitchIfEmpty.java:44)
        reactor.core.publisher.MonoSwitchIfEmpty.subscribe(MonoSwitchIfEmpty.java:44)
        reactor.core.publisher.MonoSwitchIfEmpty.subscribe(MonoSwitchIfEmpty.java:44)
        reactor.core.publisher.MonoSwitchIfEmpty.subscribe(MonoSwitchIfEmpty.java:44)
        reactor.core.publisher.MonoMapFuseable.subscribe(MonoMapFuseable.java:59)
        reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3008)
        reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.drain(FluxConcatMap.java:418)
        reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onSubscribe(FluxConcatMap.java:210)
        reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:128)
        reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:61)
        reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap.subscribe(FluxConcatMap.java:121)
        reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext.subscribe(MonoNext.java:40)
        reactor.core.publisher.MonoSwitchIfEmpty.subscribe(MonoSwitchIfEmpty.java:44)
        reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:60)
        reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:60)
        reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
        reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal.subscribe(MonoPeekTerminal.java:61)
        reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekFuseable.subscribe(MonoPeekFuseable.java:74)
        reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
        reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
        reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
        reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnErrorResume.subscribe(MonoOnErrorResume.java:44)
        reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnErrorResume.subscribe(MonoOnErrorResume.java:44)
        reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnErrorResume.subscribe(MonoOnErrorResume.java:44)
        reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3008)
        reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.drain(MonoIgnoreThen.java:167)
        reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:56)
        reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnErrorResume.subscribe(MonoOnErrorResume.java:44)
        reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal.subscribe(MonoPeekTerminal.java:61)
        reactor.ipc.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.applyHandler(ChannelOperations.java:383)
        reactor.ipc.netty.http.server.HttpServerOperations.onHandlerStart(HttpServerOperations.java:359)
        io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute$$$capture(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
        io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:403)
        io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:463)
        io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
    Error has been observed by the following operator(s):
        |_  Flux.map(ByteBufFlux.java:68)
        |_  Flux.doOnNext(ByteBufFlux.java:230)
        |_  Flux.map(ReactorServerHttpRequest.java:148)
        |_  Flux.flatMap(AbstractJackson2Decoder.java:95)
        |_  Flux.doFinally(AbstractJackson2Decoder.java:95)
        |_  Flux.map(AbstractJackson2Decoder.java:117)
        |_  Flux.singleOrEmpty(AbstractJackson2Decoder.java:87)
        |_  Operators.error(FluxReceive.java:276)
        |_  Mono.onErrorMap(DefaultServerRequest.java:146)
        |_  Mono.map(ConferenceService.kt:27)
        |_  Mono.map(ConferenceService.kt:32)
        |_  Mono.zipWith(ConferenceService.kt:47)
        |_  Mono.map(ConferenceService.kt:48)
        |_  Flux.flatMap(SimpleReactiveMongoRepository.java:318)
        |_  MonoExtensionsKt.toMono(ConferenceService.kt:55)
        |_  Mono.map(ConferenceService.kt:56)
        |_  Flux.map(AbstractJackson2Encoder.java:99)
        |_  Mono.flatMap(DispatcherHandler.java:177)
        |_  Mono.onErrorResume(DispatcherHandler.java:177)
        |_  Mono.flatMap(DispatcherHandler.java:161)
        |_  Mono.defer(DefaultWebFilterChain.java:71)
        |_  Mono.doOnSuccess(MetricsWebFilter.java:59)
        |_  Mono.doOnError(MetricsWebFilter.java:60)
        |_  Mono.compose(MetricsWebFilter.java:54)
        |_  Mono.defer(DefaultWebFilterChain.java:71)
        |_  Mono.defer(DefaultWebFilterChain.java:71)
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

#### `WebClient.exchange()` result stream is unicast

The problem here is in fact that `WebClient` allows only one subscriber per connection. If you try to subscribe to the same ***exchanged*** connection twice - you will get `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only one connection receive subscriber allowed.`

Despite the fact that I don't see where you have tried to reuse the same connection twice, I believe that you may solve that problem by using next combination of operators:

```
class GeoService() {
   val client = WebClient.create("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/")

   fun resolveGeoFromCity(city: String): Mono<Geo> {
       return client.get()
            .uri("json?address=$city&key=$API_KEY&language=en")
            .exchange()
            .flatMap { it.bodyToMono(String::class.java) }
            .map { parse(it) }
            .share();
   }
   ...
}
```

in that example, flow is configured to multicasts (shares) the original source as long as there is at least one `Subscriber` will be subscribed. 
In case if you need that all subscribers receive the same date you may replace `.share` with `.cache` operator.

Also, there is an alternative to above technique. You may replace mentioned operator with a processor and get the same sharing possibility:

```
class GeoService() {

   val client = WebClient.create("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/")

   fun resolveGeoFromCity(city: String): Mono<Geo> {
       return client.get()
            .uri("json?address=$city&key=$API_KEY&language=en")
            .exchange()
            .flatMap { it.bodyToMono(String::class.java) }
            .map { parse(it) }
            .subscribeWith(DirectProcessor.create());
   }
   ...
}
```

In that case, you subscribing and running consumption of source's data exactly right after calling `subscribeWith`, so, potentially, in that case, you may lose some part of data, etc.

#### Why with `Mono.just(..)` everything works fine?

First of all `.just` is a cold operator, it allows as many as possible subscribers which receive the same data at any point in time. That is why when you tried to consume the same chunk of data from the connection twice, you did not get any exceptions.

Comment: Hey Oleg. I think issue is rather in geo Mono dependency on item Mono. Upon subscription geo generates second subscription to item. And it is prohibited by rx-netty.

Comment: There is `share` operator in my version of Reactor. `cache` does not help

Comment: So, did some of the proposed technique help to solve your problem?

Comment: BTW, from your stack I don't see any code related to `ConferenceService`, but the error stack is directly related to this part of the code

Comment: I have applied `cache` operator to most top item, then it works okay.

Comment: @OlehDokuka This `share` operator doesn't seem to be available in newer Reactor releases and the `cache` operator is still throwing the same error. Was this functionality removed in later releases? If so, is there a new work around to allow this? Related question I had posted that is slightly different but results in the same error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56238895/webflux-call-bodytomono-twice-throws-illegalstateexception

Comment: @Bobbake4 can you please share a sample of code in your question. I will do my best help you.

Comment: Hi @OlehDokuka we have the same issue but not with Webclient. Could you direct to right documentation for understanding, logging  and troubleshooting this type of error.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. The fix was to specify this dependency:

org.springframework:spring-webflux:5.1.4.RELEASE

As I used spring-boot it deploys the previous version of it. Unfortunately, the link to this issue is not existing now.

So now my gradle looks like this:

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux')
// Next 2 dependencies are temporally here until the one above does not resolves next to at least 5.1.4 - where 
// webflux issue is resolved:
// https://github.com/rstoyanchev/spr-issue-migration-test-2/issues/17323
compile('org.springframework:spring-webflux:5.1.4.RELEASE')
compile('org.springframework:spring-web:5.1.4.RELEASE')
```

Comment: As of today that cause is no longer applicable. As expected, never versions of Spring Boot come with a later version of Spring Webflux. E. g. Spring Boot 2.7.6 comes with Webflux 5.3.24

Answer (score 0):

I've done a very similar example here:

This router will get a geolocation from name and the with another service extract the sunrise and sunset time:

I've use the [and](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#and-org.reactivestreams.Publisher-) method from Mono.

```
internal fun buildResponse(address: Mono<String>) =
        address.transform(geoLocationService::fromAddress).and(this::sunriseSunset, ::LocationResponse)

internal fun sunriseSunset(geographicCoordinates: GeographicCoordinates) =
        geographicCoordinates.toMono().transform(sunriseSunsetService::fromGeographicCoordinates)
```

More details of this [example](https://github.com/LearningByExample/KotlinReactiveMS/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/org/learning/by/example/reactive/kotlin/microservices/KotlinReactiveMS/handlers/ApiHandler.kt)