# Only one connection receive subscriber allowed

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, reactive-streams

Can someone help me with `Only one connection receive subscriber allowed.` error?

I looked at [Oleh Dokuka's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48057404/3595026) but it did not help me.

I have simplified the code for demonstration purpose. In my actual code I am getting a bulk Json request, I need to query two different tables taking two different parameters from the request body, call another service using both the results and send the result  in the response.

Router function

```java
@Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> myRoute(MyRequestHandler myRequestHandler) {

        return route(RequestPredicates.POST("/api/something"), myRequestHandler::myHandlerFunction);
    }
```

Handler function

```java
public Mono<ServerResponse> myHandlerFunction(ServerRequest serverRequest) {
        Mono<Integer> just = Mono.just(22);

//For simplification I've added String body here. In actual code I have proper json body 
        Mono<String> stringMono = serverRequest.bodyToMono(String.class);

        Mono<String> mono = stringMono.zipWith(stringMono).map(t -> t.getT2() + t.getT1());

        return ok().body(mono, String.class);
    }
```

The code is working fine if I replace `stringMono` with `just` in both the places in

`Mono<String> mono = stringMono.zipWith(stringMono).map(t -> t.getT2() + t.getT1());`

Why is it working with
`Mono<String> mono = just.zipWith(just).map(t -> t.getT2() + t.getT1());`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the `stringMono.zipWith(stringMono)` will cause Spring to attempt to subscribe to the body of the request twice which is likely your problem since the ServerRequest is unicast and can have only one subscriber.

Try this:

```
Mono<String> stringMono = serverRequest.bodyToMono(String.class).publish(body -> body.zipWith(body).map(t -> t.getT2() + t.getT1()));
```

[publish()](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#publish-java.util.function.Function-) will not cause multiple subscriptions to the body.